# Running sh shell in Busybox

Tags: kubernetes

Hope all is well. I am stuck with this Pod executing a shell script, using the BusyBox image. The one below works,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: loop
  name: busybox-loop
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |-
      for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; \
      do echo "Welcome $i times"; done
    image: busybox
    name: loop
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

But this one doesn't works as I am using "- >" as the operator,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: busybox-loop
  name: busybox-loop
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: busybox-loop
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - >
    - for i in {1..10};
    - do
    - echo ("Welcome $i times");
    - done
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Is it because the for syntax "for i in {1..10};" will not work on sh shell. As we know we don't have any other shells in Busybox or the "- >" operator is incorrect, I don't think so because it works for other shell scripts.

Also when can use "- |" multiline operator(I hope the term is correct) and "- >" operator. I know this syntax below is easy to use, but the problem is when we use double quotes in the script, the escape sequence confuses and never works.

args: ["-c", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done"]

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1):

`...But this one doesn't works as I am using "- >" as the operator...`

You don't need '-' after '>' in this case, try:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  labels:
    run: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    args:
    - ash
    - -c
    - >
      for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
      do
      echo "hello";
      done
```

`kubectl logs pod busybox` will print hello 10 times.

Comment: Thanks so much and it works as expected, But do you mean like a - after >, I didn't use that at all, maybe I didnt undertsnad well. Please explain.

Comment: Your spec in the question uses '-' for every item after '>'.

Comment: Oh great, thanks for pointing out. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Brace expansion in `for loop` is not supported by ash shell. One more solution here can be replacing it with `seq` command and update formatting like this:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: busybox-loop
    args:
    - /bin/sh 
    - -c
    - >
      for i in `seq 1 10`;
      do echo "Welcome $i times";
      done
  restartPolicy: Never
```

It doesn't matter in this case which operator to use - `- |` or `- >`, both will work fine.

Comment: Thanks very much, this one works fine. Appreciate your support. Great job!

Comment: @CelticBean, please accept the answer if that works for you and fully satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use this command to create the pod:

```
$ kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --dry-run=client -o yaml --command -- /bin/sh -c "for i in {1..10}; do echo 'Welcome $i times'; done" | kubectl apply -f -
  pod/busybox created

$ kubectl logs busybox                                                                                                                                          
  Welcome 10 times
```

Note that you can take a look into YAML created by the dry run command as well.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: busybox
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - for i in {1..10}; do echo 'Welcome $i times'; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did tried this but I used double quotes in the echo and swapped there and here trying to get out of the escape sequence nothing worked and I tried your solutions it just prints a line, vagrant@kubemaster:~$ kubectl logs busybox
Welcome  times